# jacoco 0 percentage code coverage all 2 branches missed

Tags: jacoco

Hi I am trying to run jacoco code coverage and getting all 2 branches missed error and my code coverage is 0.0% all the times how much i tried to write test case for below code..

```
public void someSchedulerJob(){
    if (true) {
        log.info("Run Job");

        try {
            //few method calls which needs to be run every day
        } catch (Exceptionexp) {
            log.error("Exception doing scheduler job "+ exp);
        }    
    }else{
        log.info("Disabled Scheduler Job");
    }
}
```

how to make code coverage report for this method using junit 100%

Regards

Comment: How are you pulling JaCoCo into your project? Are you using the Maven plugin? If so, can you include your pom.xml?

Comment: Yes pulling out via pom.xml with maven plugin for other files it's working fine for one class with that method it's not working...

Comment: Could you update your question to include the pom.xml?

Comment: <plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.7.8</version>
    <executions>
     <execution>
      <id>jacoco-initialize</id>
      <goals>
       <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
      </goals>
     </execution>
     <execution>
      <id>jacoco-site</id>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
       <goal>report</goal>
      </goals>
     </execution>
    </executions>
   </plugin>

Comment: Is that plugin in the build section of the pom or the reporting section? I just created an empty Maven project, dropped that plugin into the build section, made a class with the method above, wrote a one-line JUnit test to call the method, then ran `mvn clean package` and it gave me non-zero coverage on the class.

Comment: can you please get me the one-line of junit test to call the method?

Comment: It's no different than how you would call the method any other time. If the class is `Example`, then the test just calls `new Example().someSchedulerJob();`

Comment: if i call the method by mocking the class object it still say All 2 branches missed with 0% code coverage.

Comment: That's your problem - you shouldn't be mocking the class you're trying to test. By mocking the class you're not actually testing it. If you want to test the class you need to create a real instance of it, not a mock.